# How to loop on rows HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have been scrapping for a long time now just started learning HtmlAgilityPack.

I am not sure how to loop through items as it brings back the same item each time.

Code:

```
  HtmlNodeCollection nodesMatchingXPath = mainNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='ad_listitem']");
               if (nodesMatchingXPath.Count > 0)
               {
                   foreach (HtmlNode hn in nodesMatchingXPath)
                   {

                       HtmlNode title = hn.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='name_psb_link hover_text_decoration']");
                       if (title != null)
                       {
                         // SAME TITLE EACH TIME MEANING SOMETHING TO DO WITH XPATH
                       }
                    }
                }
```

I see it doea get all the items as the count is 200 , but not sure if this is the rite way to loop through them or something to do with the path which brings back the same info each time, maybe its searching on whole document instead of that single node.

Comment: Show us the HTML you are running against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath expression starting with `/` (like your `"//a[@class='name_psb_link hover_text_decoration']"`) always starts from the root, not from the current node!

Start with a `.` (like `".//a[@class='name_psb_link hover_text_decoration']"`) to start from the current node.

Comment: Sorry works now might have been doing something else before :).